# Performance: search for values and return the sub arrays' key

Tags: php, performance

Given an array like:

```
$nouns = array(
    "man" => array("men"),
    "octopus" => array("octopi", "octopuses"),
    "ox" => array("oxen")
);
```

Consisting of approximately 3000 singular - plural pairs, how would one get the singular (the key) the most efficiently, by calling, for example, `array_search_loosely($nouns, "men")`?

I then expect to receive an array with the value "man".

I have tried four different approaches:

**Original** (which uses the function `array_is_assoc`, which is rather self-explanatory and irrelevant to the situation)

```
function array_search_loosely($array, $values, $compare_keys = false) {
  $values = is_array($values) ? $values : array($values);
  foreach($array as $item_key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
      $return_key = true;
      foreach($values as $value_key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, $item)) {
          $return_key = false;
          break;
        }
        elseif($compare_keys === true and array_is_assoc($values)) {
          if (!in_array($value_key, array_keys($item, $value))) {
            $return_key = false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if ($return_key === true) {
        $item_keys[] = $item_key;
      }
    }
    elseif(!is_array($values)) {
      if ($item === $values) {
        $item_keys[] = $item_key;
      }
    }
  }
  return (isset($item_keys))? $item_keys : false;
}
```

**Second approach**:

```
function array_search_loosely($array, $values, $compare_keys = false) {
    $keys = array_keys(array_filter($array, function($item) use ($values, $compare_keys) {
        return (!is_array($item) and $item === $values) or (is_array($item) and each_in_array($item, array_create($values), $compare_keys));
    }));
    return !empty($keys) ? $keys : false;
}

function each_in_array($array, $values, $compare_keys = false) {
    return $compare_keys === false ? count(array_uintersect($values, $array, function($item1, $item2) { return $item1 === $item2 ? 0 : ($item1 > $item2 ? 1 : -1); })) == count($values) : count(array_uintersect_assoc($values, $array, function($item1, $item2) { return $item1 === $item2 ? 0 : ($item1 > $item2 ? 1 : -1); })) == count($values);
}
```

I chose to use `array_uintersect`, to also allow arrays to be `$items`, because if I was to use array_intersect, notices would be generated for each array `$item`. This choice allows `each_in_array()` to check for array `$values` as well.

Also, the third optional parameter `$compare_keys` is not relevant for this situation, but is in other situations where I use the function.

The third and fourth approaches were mixtures of the preceding. At this point my original approach would still be the fastest, but when I run my function on a few hundred or thousand words, the operation will still cost several tens of seconds. Any suggestions on how to improve the performance of getting a plurals singular in this situation?

Comment: "I then expect to receive an array with the value "man"." - is this vital? wouldn't a string be more useful?

Comment: Sometimes two singulars have the same plural, which means multiple keys should be returned. (data, datum => data) Also, this is especially vital in other applications of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your map in its current format is not good to do the lookup. You also need an inversion of it:

```
$invert = array(
  'men' => 'man',
  'octopi' => 'octopus',
  'octopuses' => 'octopus',
  'oxen' => 'ox',
);
```

Comment: Some singulars have the same plural, unfortunately. Mostly greek and latin loan words

Comment: And that causes any problems for you?

Comment: Keep those out of the index. Because that are not so many cases. So in general the lookup is fast, but for those it ain't.

Comment: Do you suggest a separate array for singulars that have the same plural? Or in my original approach: a separate array for singulars with multiple plurals. That is messy and perhaps hard to maintain though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = 'men';
$found  = '';

foreach($nouns AS $noun => $values){
   if(in_array($search, $values){
        echo 'Found what we\'re looking for.';
        $found = $nouns[$noun];
   }

}

print_r($found);
```

Answer (score 0):

output:

[image: output]
source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $nouns = array  (
                                "data" => array("data"),
                                "datum" => array("data"),
                                "man" => array("men"),
                                "octopus" => array("octopi", "octopuses"),
                                "ox" => array("oxen"),
                                "hippopotamus" => array("hippopotami", "hippopotamuses")
                            );

            function find_singular($nouns, $search)
            {
                foreach($nouns as $noun => $values)
                {
                    if(in_array($search, $values))
                    {
                        $found[] = $noun;
                    }
                }
                if(!empty($found))
                {
                    $n = count($found);
                    if($n > 1)
                    {
                        echo "<strong>$search</strong> has $n singular forms: <em>";
                        print_r(implode('</em> and <em>', $found).'</em><br />');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<b>$search</b> is the plural of <em>$found[0]</em><br />";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<b>$search</b> was not found.<br />";
                }
            }

            find_singular($nouns, "men");
            find_singular($nouns, "octopi");
            find_singular($nouns, "data");
            find_singular($nouns, "oxen");
            find_singular($nouns, "octopuses");
            find_singular($nouns, "hippopotami");
            find_singular($nouns, "kittens");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

hope this helps!

EDIT:
what is the purpose of this? I am guessing you are creating a dictionary application for a web or app interface. I don't think you're going to be able to avoid loops so long as you intend on implementing a search ability. are you storing the whole dictionary in a PHP array? I assume you are since XML and mysql queries would cost even more time. my only other suggestion would be to split the dictionary into as many arrays you can manage (perhaps a few dozen per alphabetic letter) else write a script to produce these from either the existing dictionary array or a flat file, and then implement AJAX in your search box, similar to Google's predictive search but instead of displaying possible results as the search string is typed, it would be narrowing down which array to search, silently in the background. I have a script somewhere which does this and can dig it up if this sounds viable. basically, instead of searching the whole dictionary (I have seen one with in excess of twelve million words!) per keyword, by the time the keyword is typed, sent and processed, there could be much fewer loop cycles. hardware also springs to mind - the hard disk, processor and memory speeds of the server will account for most of the equation. I have also heard that C++ is much more suited to dictionary searches and would not be too foreign an option for a PHP developer.

Comment: $values is possibly an array of values (although perhaps not necessarily in this situation). Anyway... I already did exactly this in my original approach. I was hoping for something that doesn't involve looping, because otherwise there will never be any significant speed improvement and I will have to stick to what I already had. And since some singulars have multiple plurals while some plurals have multiple singulars (-on (greek) & -um (latin) are often -a in plural), it won't help to flip my current array.